# How to set the background image of a form dynamically on load?

Tags: c#, winforms

Just create a new windows form application in C# and try this code it does not work as desired:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap rBitmap = new Bitmap(600, 500);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(rBitmap);
    LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 500), Color.DeepSkyBlue, Color.Green, LinearGradientMode.Vertical);
    brush.SetSigmaBellShape(0.0f, 1f);
    graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 500));
    Form1.ActiveForm.BackgroundImage = rBitmap;
}
```

The form loads with defaults. If you add a button to the form and add the same code, it works as desired setting the background image of the form. So how do you accomplish this dynamically in the Form1_Load event so an image is displayed when the program is opened?

Comment: `this.BackgroundImage = rBitmap;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form isn't active during the load event:

Try:

```
this.BackgroundImage = rBitmap;
```

And dispose of your objects when you are done:

```
Bitmap rBitmap = new Bitmap(600, 500);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rBitmap)) {
  using (var br = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 500),
         Color.DeepSkyBlue, Color.Green, LinearGradientMode.Vertical)) {
    br.SetSigmaBellShape(0.0f, 1f);
    g.FillRectangle(br, new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 500));
  }
}
this.BackgroundImage = rBitmap;
```

Comment: Sorry I copy/pasted the text from the helpful hint thing when you write a comment. lol.